# Passing data from PHP to JS and JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I'm trying to learn PHP and javascript, therefore I tried to do an exercise about passing data but I didn't understand the js function and currently unable to do anything.

Here is the code

php-code.php

```
$v1=$_GET['v1'];
$v2=$_GET['v2'];
$v3=$_GET['v3'];
//Some operations about them
echo $output;
```

my-js.js

```
var v1 = $('#v1 option:selected').val();
var v2 = $('#v2 option:selected').val();
var v3 = $('#v3 option:selected').val();
//This is where I want to pass these variables to my php file and get the output
//But i don't know how
```

js-execute.php

```
//this is where my js gets the variables at first
```

Comment: To my knowledge, it doesn't work that way. PHP executes first. Then Javascript.

Comment: PHP runs on the server, javascript normally runs on the client. By the time the javascript runs the PHP has already finished execution. You can't pass variables that way, you'll need techniques such as AJAX.

Comment: oh i see, what i was trying to do is run the php file in js file by passing the variables to it and getting the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is a server-side language while JavaScript is a client-side one. This means that PHP will be executed when someone requests a page, but the browser will only get the result of the PHP code. On the other hand, JavaScript is sent to the browser and the browser will execute it at the appropriate time (when the page loads or when an event happens). That's why if you look at the source code of a page, you will be able to see the JavaScript code, but never the PHP code.

If you want to pass values from JavaScript to PHP, you will need to make a remote call to a PHP file. PHP isn't like JavaScript – once it's done running its code, it won't be able to respond to anything without a reload of the page.

The easiest way to send something to a PHP file and fetching the result with JavaScript can probably be achieved with JQuery. It has a function `$.get` which will fetch a given URL. Just be sure to properly validate the input on the server side – never trust user input.

JavaScript (using JQuery to send `v1`, `v2` and `v3` to page.php)

```
function requestPage(v1, v2, v3) {
   $.get('page.php', {'v1':v1, 'v2':v2, 'v3':v3}, function(data) {
      alert(data);
   });
}
```

PHP (a trivial example)

```
// Be sure to properly validate input!
if(isset($_GET['v1']) && is_scalar($_GET['v1'])) {
   echo strrev($_GET['v1']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but can't i just use
$.get('page.php', {'v1':v1, 'v2':v2, 'v3':v3}, alert(data));

why is the response function is there

Comment: Yes, you can. Supplying another function name is useful if you have a lot of stuff to do on `data`. Another possibility is to put the function body as the parameter. I'll update my answer to show this alternative as it's quite common practice in JavaScript.